# How to add items to array field in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `Shop`.It is defined as below

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.TextField()
    items = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField()))
```

Now I want to add multiple items to the `items` field for the same shop.Currently to add one item to the `Shop` model, this is how I do it

```
@csrf_exempt
def shopping(request):
    user_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    if request.method == "POST":
        if user_request.get("action") == "add":
            conv = Shop.objects.create(
            name=user_request.get("name"),
            city=user_request.get("city"),
            items=user_request.get("itme")
            )
            return HttpResponse(1)
```

But it only stores one item for the particular `name`.So I need to append more items. How do I append to an arrayfield?

Comment: You can use Json Field

Comment: Did you try `.append()`?

Comment: are you sure `itme`?